# Using combobox (select) with multiple selection on phonegap

Tags: cordova, combobox

I'm trying to add to my phonegap project a combobox with multiple selection.

```
<select id="filtersList" multiple style="width:400px;">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

The native selector for selecting values from the combo works and looks great (currently testing on android),
but my problem is with how the values are displayed - since it displays only the first item from the list that is selected,
so if there is more than one value selected, then the user cannot know about this from looking at the combobox and he will have to open the selector to see all of the selected items.

Anyone have an idea of how can I fix this ?

I tried to play with the `-webkit-appearance` but that didn't give a good solution.

I thought of an idea of maybe to display all of the selected items in a different div, and to create a trigger that when clicking on that div, then it would trigger an event that opens the selector of the combobox, but I couldn't find a way to open the selector programmaticly.